# Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Ошибка с анимацией. Помогите

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Хочу сделать анимацию для игры. Возникла ошибка: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Upravlenie.set_State (CharState value) (at Assets/Upravlenie.cs:20).
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upravlenie : MonoBehaviour {

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    public float verticalImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    bool Running = false;

    private Animator animator;

    private CharState State
    {
        get { return (CharState)animator.GetInteger("State"); }
        set { animator.SetInteger("State", (int)value); }
    }

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    public void LeftButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Run;
    }

    public void RightButtonDown()
    {   speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Run;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        speedX = 0;
    }
    public void OnClickJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        if (!isGrounded) State = CharState.Jump;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Idle;

    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = true;
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = false;
     }
}

public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Скриншот из аниматора:[image: Аниматор]

Сому анимацию ТОЧНО сделал правильно

Мне нужна помощь взаимодействия анимации с кодом.
Прошу помочь.
P.S. Управление сделал через кнопки Button и добавил компонент event triger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя не хватает как раз той самой переменной `State`, на которую и будет реагировать анимация. Посмотри пример ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут можно видеть 4 переменных (параметра): два float, bool и trigger.

Всё, что передается из скрипта — устанавливается во вкладке `Parameters` (ну и наоборот, может доставаться).

А вот `Conditions` (которое справа) уже реагирует на ту самую внутреннюю переменную меканима.

---

Также ты забыл сделать при старте `animator = GetComponent<Animator>();`, чтобы инициализировать переменную. И проблема скорее всего даже именно в этом)

Comment: Перезалил скрин. Ты про это?

Comment: @max5937 ты забыл кстати сделать при старте `animator = GetComponent<Animator>();`

Comment: хммм... анимация появилась, но она появляется при нажатии кнопки и пропадает через секунду и персонаж двигается опять не поднимая ноги.

Comment: @max5937 возможно это потому, что у тебя в `FixedUpdate` прописано `if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Idle;` и возможно когда персонаж на земле, то это действие отрабатывается много раз в секунду, в итоге оно постоянно стремится в `Idle`;

Comment: изменил на Update - вообще пропала анимация(кроме idle, она крутиться всегда), вернул опять FixedUpdate, появилась ошибка: Socket: failed to shutdown stream, error: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
(0).

Comment: убрал из фикса  if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Idle; и всё заработало. Только теперь в Idle не переходит

Comment: Ошибка:  Socket: failed to shutdown stream, error: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. Пропала

Comment: Решил последнею проблему сам. Спасибо за помощь в остальном

Comment: @max5937 в Idle не переходит потому, что надо либо hasExitedTime галочку поставить для текущей анимации, либо стрелочку в Animator от нужного состояния направить в какую-либо сторону, например в тот же Idle и прописать условие перехода в неё. Если есть вопросы - лучше задавай их на ресурсе, не в комментарии)